# Usage of comma in context

Tags: commas

This is a sentence from Wikipedia:

> The Chevrolet Corvette **,** known colloquially as the Vette or Chevy Corvette **,** is a sports car manufactured by Chevrolet.

Is the placement of comma before *known* and *is* correct?

When we have to give additional info about a noun, we place commas to enclose the phrase, e.g. "Saraswati, the goddess of knowledge, is..."

But somehow, here, its usage seems wrong to me; especially the one before *is*. What's the rule to be followed for such cases?

Comment: It is correct. It is additional information that is not necessarily important and the sentence would still make sense if you were to remove that portion of it.

Comment: Adding too @Timinycricket 's comment, the two commas contain a clause which could be entirely removed and the sentence still makes sense, though losing information. I'l note though, that it is not correct for the commas to be preceded by a space.

Comment: I agree with the point that the clause contains additional info, which if removed, the sentence would still make sense; but somehow, putting a comma before is seemed wrong. Moreover, I put a space before the comma just to bold it.